# jQuery ui button image not displaying

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I´ve tried to use a jQuery Ui button with an image. So i wrote the following code:

```
$("#analyse_button").button({ icons: { primary: "fb-icon" } });

.fb-icon {
    background-image: url(./fb-icon.png);
}
```

As you see in the screenshot below the background-image is overriden by the standard ui-icon background-image but even if i remove this my image is still not being displayed.

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbWbi.png)

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to increase the priority of your CSS rule it should be defined this way:

```
.ui-state-default .fb-icon {
    background-image: url(./fb-icon.png);
}
```

Comment: so that worked now it`s no longer overriden but it`s still not displaying..
any others ideas?

Comment: Try to adjust the position of the image with `background-position`.

Comment: that worked too (;
now one last question: how to i resize the icon?

Comment: You can use `background-size` property, but it's not supported in IE<9, so better to use already sized icon.